# How to make jQuery effects run in sequence, not simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I have two effects in jQuery run in `sequence`, not simultaneously? Take this piece of code for example:

```
$("#show-projects").click(function() {
    $(".page:visible").fadeOut("normal");
    $("#projects").fadeIn("normal");
});
```

The `fadeOut` and the `fadeIn` run simultaneously, how do I make them run one after the other?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can supply a callback to the effects functions that run after the effect has completed.

```
$("#show-projects").click(function() {
    $(".page:visible").fadeOut("normal", function() {
        $("#projects").fadeIn("normal");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 16):

What you want is a queue.

Check out the reference page http://api.jquery.com/queue/ for some working examples.

Comment: .queue() is a element only function. If you have different animation targets this won't work.

Comment: I don't see how it wouldn't work; you can explicitly name the target in the callback, right?

Comment: What if there is no target. I don't think Queue would work for me here as my two methods I want sequentially launching refer to different targets.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "#foo" ).fadeOut( 300 ).delay( 800 ).fadeIn( 400 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Does there have to be a target? surely you can use a random target to queue events sequentially so long as the target is constant...below I'm using the parent of an animation target to store the queue.

```
//example of adding sequential effects through
//event handlers and a jquery event trigger
jQuery( document ).unbind( "bk_prompt_collapse.slide_up" );
jQuery( document ).bind( "bk_prompt_collapse.slide_up" , function( e, j_obj ) {
    jQuery(j_obj).queue(function() {
        //running our timed effect
        jQuery(this).find('div').slideUp(400);
        //adding a fill delay to the parent
        jQuery(this).delay(400).dequeue();
    });
});                     
//the last action removes the content from the dom
//if its in the queue then it will fire sequentially
jQuery( document ).unbind( "bk_prompt_collapse.last_action" );
jQuery( document ).bind( "bk_prompt_collapse.last_action" , function( e, j_obj ) {
    jQuery(j_obj).queue(function() {
        //Hot dog!!
        jQuery(this).remove().dequeue();
    });
});
jQuery("tr.bk_removing_cart_row").trigger( 
    "bk_prompt_collapse" , 
    jQuery("tr.bk_removing_cart_row") 
);
```

Not sure if its possible but it seems like you could bind .dequeue() to fire when another jquery event fires, instead of firing inline in my example above? effectively halting an animation queue?